# jQuery Mobile Navbar, why does this work?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

So I had problem with ui-btn-active because this class is removed when going to new page which means I don't get an active state on the link when navigating back through navbar:

```
<section id="main" data-role="page">
<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
  <h1>My Site</h1>
  <nav data-role="navbar">          
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#main" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#third">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#secondary">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fourth">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I used this:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerchange', function (evt,ui) {
   $(ui.toPage.attr('id') "[data-role='navbar']").addClass('ui-page-active');
});
```

This will add the class to the correct anchor, which I want, but is the space in: $(ui.toPage.attr('id') "[data-role='navbar']") correct jQuery standard? If it is, where can I read about this? Why is it added to anchor instead of the nav? I'm rather new to jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Changing $("[data-role='navbar']").navbar(); to $("[data-role='panel'] [data-role='navbar']").navbar(); seems to have worked

Comment: `$("[data-role='navbar']").navbar();` isnt in your question. if you code has changed please update it in the question so that other people with the same problem can be helped